# How are hot questions selected?

Tags: discussion

What puts a question on the hot list, an algorithm?

Comment: It requires answers, and both the question and answers need to be upvoted.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones ...without much delay after posting it. Only new questions go into HNQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hot questions are fully automatic.

See the [hot questions tag info on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-questions/info):

> “Hot questions” can refer to two things:
>
> - the list of “Hot Network Questions” in the right sidebar, also available as the [“hot” tab of the main Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)
> - the “hot” tab on each question and answer site
>
> In both cases, questions are included if they hit a large “hotness” in a short time, with hotness determined by score, views and number of answers. The formulas for both cases are different; e.g. questions without answers never appear on the Hot Network Questions, but can appear on a site's "hot" tab.
>
> The "hot" tab of the per-site meta is used to obtain questions to show in the "Hot Meta Posts" block part of the [community-bulletin](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-bulletin) on the main site; for questions about that, use that tag as well.
>
> The network-wide list has further adjustments to avoid being completely dominated by a site, and entire sites can be excluded from the list on a case-by-case basis. Inclusion is fully automatic, and cannot be controlled even by moderators (not without major side effects such as closing the question).
>
> #### Useful links
>
> - [How questions get included in the Hot Network Questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page)
> - [How questions get included in a site's “hot” tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page)
> - [What is the Goal of "Hot Network Questions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)

Comment: My top question ever is [this one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/25280/is-it-rude-to-ask-my-opponent-to-resign-an-online-game-when-they-have-a-lost-end). If it is an algorithm based on votes and answers I think it is much more complex to add a hot question here than on chess. [This is the only one I puted on host list](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/25280/is-it-rude-to-ask-my-opponent-to-resign-an-online-game-when-they-have-a-lost-end)

Comment: I think here Muze is the only one who reached many hot questions (and uhoh). He asked generical. I have questions abour geology, but may ask questions that migth interest a bigger public

Comment: @Universal_learner Your linked post [did become a hot network question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/25280/timeline#history_58668c65-f44d-4248-a026-55e2d28e470f). I agree that on science sites it's hard to get to hot questions because only a limited number of people can answer (interpersonal skills, travel, academia are easy to get on hot network questions). Questions I've asked on Stats often got less than ten views in a week...

Comment: The only question I puted here is [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17411/why-doesnt-sea-level-show-seasonality) It only has two answers. They were quick. Also the upvotes on question came quick. I realized Muze hot questions are allways generical, not too much technical.

Comment: @Universal_learner [This question by uhoh is currently hot](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19304/6).

Comment: @Universal_learner I've added a feed that posts new hot network questions from Earth Science to [chat].